# Question regarding video card support / monitor resolution

Tags: boot, drivers, ati

I have set up a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 using  a bootable USB for the install process and while in the 'try ubuntu' enviroment there were no problems at all.

After installing Ubuntu, my PC booted and started GRUB but ended up with a a black screen issue, which I resolved by entering `radeon.modeset=0`. I know that this means that there is some sort of incompatibility with the video card `Radeon HD 6620`.

I tried to address this issue before by going into the <kbd>Additional drivers</kbd> window and clicked the option to install the proprietary driver but I don't believe I did it correctly, because after that, the GRUB screen was black again.

I notices that every time I boot into Ubuntu I have to enter (radeon.modeset=0), to get output to the monitor. This however is no where near to the resolution that I was getting from the bootable USB 'Try Ubuntu'.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in a terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Find the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line anc change it so it looks like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"`

Hit Ctrl+O then Enter to save and Ctrl+X to exit. Now run in the terminal:

`sudo update-grub`

The `radeon.modeset=0` paremeter will be now automatically appended to the kernel during boot time. Reboot and see.